# Ordering Model based on a max Children Attribute (with potential ties) - Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to sort my `Docket` object based on the most recent Document (a child object). There are typically several documents with the same `date_filed`. Based on the tutorial, I tried sorting on `-documents__date_filed` and it sort of works. Because there are multiple Documents with the exact same date, my ListView shows 2-3 repeated rows (one for each date tie). How do I avoid getting the duplicated results and just have one row for each Docket in the output?

```
class Docket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-documents__date_filed', Func(F('name'), function='LOWER')]

class Document(models.Model):
    docket = models.ForeignKey(Docket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="documents")
    date_filed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to do the ordering in the `ListView` itself if it includes a related model, since now nearly all `Docker.objects.all()` querysets will have duplicates.

You can make use of [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve a queryset of `Docket` objects where the same one only occurs once:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class DocketListView(ListView):
    model = Docket
    queryset = Docket.objects.order_by(
        '-documents__date_filed',
        Lower('name')
    ).distinct()
```